# change text or language mui mobile date picker react js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, react-datepicker

how to change the text "clear", or change the language of this inscription?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpO8U.png)

```js
<LocalizationProvider adapterLocale={ru} dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                                <MobileDatePicker
                                    inputFormat={"dd.MM.yyyy"}
                                    closeOnSelect={true}
                                     inputProps={{
                                        ...params.inputProps,
                                        placeholder: "date",
                                        style : { fontWeight : "bold", color : "#555" }
                                    }} />}  />
                        </LocalizationProvider>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution

```js
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterJalali} localeText={{ cancelButtonLabel: "example", okButtonLabel: "example", clearButtonLabel: "example" }}>
  ...
</LocalizationProvider>
```